# /phppgadmin Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phppgadmin/ on this server

Tags: postgresql, server, debian-jessie, phppgadmin

I recently upgrade my server from Debian Wheezy to Debian Jessie (Debian 8).
A lot of packages was updated and now, I don't have the right to access to phppgadmin from http://myIP/phppgadmin

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phppgadmin/ on this server.
```

I try a lot of thinks to solve the problem but absolutely nothing works...

In /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin:

```
Alias /phppgadmin /usr/share/phppgadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phppgadmin>

DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride None

order allow,deny
# deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
allow from all
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf I add:

```
    <Directory /usr/share/phppgadmin/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I try to change the permissions of /usr/share/phppgadmin/, /var/www...

And I have the same message even if I uninstall the package phpgpadmin !

```
apt-get remove phppgadmin
```

Big thanks for help...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Debian 8, apache2 configurations are now in `/etc/apache2/conf-available` and soft-linked from `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` when enabled, just like virtualhosts or modules.

The `phppgadmin` package in its latest version comes with a predefined configuration file:
  `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phppgadmin.conf`

This configuration should be activated by default, but otherwise it can be activated with `a2enconf phppgadmin`

Your old configuration `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin` should be removed as well as the mentioned addition in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

Then edit `phppgadmin.conf` and remove the `Require local` directive that you don't want if you previously had `Allow from all`.

Comment: The config refactoring has puzzled me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

you can easily solve this problem by replacing `Require local` directive to `Allow from all` in configuration file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phppgadmin.conf`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When adding an answer to an older question with an existing accepted answer it is helpful to note how your new answer differs and what additional information it brings to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're using Apache 2.4, you must replace `Require local` directive to `Require all granted`